# How to solve PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath() error on laravel version update?

Tags: php, laravel, version

I'm trying to update the laravel version from 5.3 to 5.4 but when I run the `composer update` command I got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath() in /my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:179
Stack trace:
#0 /my-project/vendor/carbonate/environmentconfig/src/EnvironmentConfig.php(49): base_path()
#1 /my-project/bootstrap/app.php(16): Carbonate\EnvironmentConfig\EnvironmentConfig::get()
#2 /my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(289): Application->storagePath()
#3 /my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(271): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bindPathsInContainer()
#4 /my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(147): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->setBasePath()
#5 /my-project/bootstrap/app.php(21): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct()
```

I follow this guide to do the update: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

I also try deleting the vendor folder and composer.lock file and running the command `composer install`, but I got the same error.

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The installer doesn't generate .env, and most likely due to APP_KEY not being set due to the missing file, PHPUnit throws this exception.

Try these commands:

```
composer run-script post-root-package-install
php artisan key:generate
```